# How to re-enable passwords remembering in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, passwords, password-management

I told Firefox to stop asking to remember passwords on a site, but now i would like to re-enable it. I looked around in FF and couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

Edit → Preferences → Security → Passwords/Exceptions

and remove the site from the list in the dialog box. Also make sure that "Remember passwords for sites" is marked.

Comment: yay! problem solved :)

Comment: with the Windows version, the path to sucess is slightly different: Tools → Options → Security → Passwords/Exceptions